# In what formal system is Godel's Incompleteness Theorem (or similar statements of undecidability) proven?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, meta-math, metalogic

For example, consider the proof using Rosser's trick as shown on wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick#The_Rosser_sentence

That proof isn't inside the arithmetical theory T, but in some higher level meta-theory. So if I wanted to do meta-reasoning about Godel's proof (or Rosser's etc), I would need a system that could refer to or even encode statements like "For any fixed arithmetical theory $T$, let Proof$_T(x,y)$..." In what formal system would the statement "For any fixed arithmetical theory $T$..." exist? It obviously wouldn't be in $T$ itself since that would be tantamount to a proof that $T$ is consistent that is inside $T$, in which case $T$ would be inconsistent by Godel's second incompleteness theorem, thus making $T$ useless as a formal system. Is it second order logic? ZFC?

Comment: No problem to prove Godel's theorems inside PA. The conditions for T are given in the statement of the theorem. The most concrete way is to assume Proof reduces to a program (Turing machine) enumerating its theorems, be consistent, and able to encode the halting problem.

Answer (score 7):

You write

> It obviously wouldn't be in $T$ itself since that would be tantamount to a proof that $T$ is consistent that is inside $T$.

This is a common misconception. The incompleteness theorem, **appropriately phrased**, can be proved in (first-order) $\mathsf{PA}$ or indeed much less. Here's the precise statement of the theorem:

- Suppose $T$ is a computably axiomatizable consistent theory which interprets Robinson arithmetic. Then $T$ is incomplete.

Note that consistency is folded into the hypothesis. In particular $\mathsf{PA}$ **can** prove

- If $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent, then it is incomplete

(since it's easy for $\mathsf{PA}$ to prove that $\mathsf{PA}$ is computably axiomatizable and interprets Robinson arithmetic), but this doesn't contradict the inability of $\mathsf{PA}$ to prove its own consistency.

---

That said, there is a "fundamentally meta" aspect to the claim that the incompleteness theorem can be proved in $\mathsf{PA}$.

What $\mathsf{PA}$ *actually* proves is a sentence $(*)$ about numbers, which **we claim** is a faithful rephrasing of "Every computably axiomatizable consistent theory interpreting Robinson arithmetic is incomplete" in some sense. But where is *that* claim made and evaluated?

Basically, on some level we have to commit to the position that a particular formal system successfully describes (at least to a certain extent) the behavior of formal systems themselves. This can feel like a bit of a rabbit hole, but remember: we do need [to start with *something*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles).

Comment: You nicely put into words what bugs me for several years now: The position that a particular formal system duccessfully describes (...) the behaviour of formal systems themselves. Do you know any more reading material on this special point?